# How to fetch large datasets into List of Strings with Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I want to fetch large datasets from a MySql database, and return it as a `List` of comma separated `String`s via a Webservice (not via a downloadable file, but directly as text).
Therefore I first need all selected rows in `CSV` format.

**Question: What's the best way achieving this with Spring?**

The following works with `JdbcTemplate`, but I don't know if this is the best approach (maybe optimize using Java 8 streams)?

Also if somehow feels wrong having to iterate the `ResultSet` and call `rs.getString(i)`, concatenating each element of the `ResultSet`. Isn't there a more elegant way?

```
RowMapper<String> rowMapper = new RowMapper<String>() {
    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            sb.append(rs.getString(i)).append(",");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
};

String sql = "SELECT * from mypersons where age > 12";
List<String> list = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).query(sql, params, rowMapper);

//...return the list via Webservice
```

Sidenote: I have to use native SQL for the select. They are much more complicated in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Spring Data JPA to get a SET of persons.  Once you have a set of persons, you can use streams to map the persons to the field you want to collect, and join that field with commas.

Assuming a Set, given a person has an attribute called name, this method will return a comma separated list of names.

```
    public String joinName(Set<Person> persons) {
       return persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
```

Comment: I have to use native SQL for the select. They are much more complicated in my example above.

Comment: @membersound you can use native queries with Spring Data just fine.

Comment: @JensSchauder can you give an example? Precaution: I want to read the native sql statements from an external file. So I cannot eg set them as `static String` on a `JpaRepository` inside the code.

Comment: This is just a really convoluted way to join all values of a single column, but the OP wants all columns joined into one String.

Comment: Well, you can have a custom implementation of a query method and load your SQL in there from a file. Having said that, Spring Data really doesn't help you here, since you would still need to join all the columns, and the `JdbcTemplate` is the right abstraction for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine. I just have two possible improvements:

1. the indexed based access to the `ResultSet` already exists in the `ColumnMapRowMapper`. You could delegate to it and would get (pseudocode)

   ```
   class CommaSeparatedStringRowMapper implements RowMapper<String> {
       ColumnMapRowMapper delegate = new ColumnMapRowMapper();

   @Override
   public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum){
       delegate.mapRow(rs, rowNum).valueSet().toStream.collect(Collectors)
   }
   ```

   *Note: this will be less efficient, due to creating and accessing the intermediate map, but it looks nicer.*

   *Note 2: The underlying map should preserve the order of columns, but you better double check.*
2. Alternatively, you might consider using a `RowCallbackHandler` writing your results directly into a Webservice response thingy. If done right, part of your response might be on the way to your client while you are still processing the rest of the query result. So this might improve latency and memory consumption.